# Responsive text values in an HTML select menu?

Tags: html, css

I have a select menu like:

```html
<select>
<option value="1">New York</option>
<option value="2">Los Angeles</option>
</select>
```

On small screens, I would prefer to use abbreviations

```html
<select>
<option value="1">NY</option>
<option value="2">LA</option>
</select>
```

How can I switch between the short and long text dynamically?

My first thought was to use media queries on `<span>` elements inside the `<option>` tags, but that doesn't work because `<option>` can only have text as children:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select>
<option value="1"><span class="d-md-none">NY</span><span class="d-none d-md-inline-block">New York</span></option>
<option value="2"><span class="d-md-none">LA</span><span class="d-none d-md-inline-block">Los Angeles<span></option>
</select>
```

I could also imagine having different `<option>` tags show/hide based on media queries:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select>
<option value="1-small" class="d-md-none">NY</option>
<option value="1-large" class="d-none d-md-block">New York</option>
<option value="2-small" class="d-md-none">LA</option>
<option value="2-large" class="d-none d-md-block">Los Angeles</option>
</select>
```

That kind of works, but it is a bit messy when you consider what it needs to do when the user resizes a window and the currently-selected value needs to switch between "-small" and "-large" - not impossible with some JS I guess, but it doesn't feel right that JS would be required to achieve this. Also feels messy that whatever code is consuming this would then need to be aware of the "-small" and "-large" suffixes in the value.

I know I could use some custom HTML/JS select menu component, but I'd prefer not to do that because using a native select menu has a lot of advantages.

It feels like there should be some better answer, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: is this list rendered dynamically?  if it is you can check the window width and render the options accordingly

Comment: @FaizalHussain that's true, but it doesn't handle the user resizing the window to be something less than full width.

Comment: Use JavaScript to update the text content of the `options` based on the window width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to determine the text that goes inside the options based on the window’s size.

> not impossible with some JS I guess, but it doesn't feel right that JS would be required to achieve this.

It can be done with no JavaScript as long as the `select` tag has its `size` attribute set to a number greater than 1. This makes the `select` render as a list and not a drop-down menu. That might not be what you need, but at least no JavaScript is required.

The solution involves pseudo-elements:

```css
option {
  font-size: 0;
}

option::before {
  font-size: 1rem;
  content: attr(value);
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {

  option::before {
    content: attr(title);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<select size='2'>
<option class="responsive-option" value="NY" title='New York'>New York</option>
<option class="responsive-option" value="LA" title='Los Angeles'>Los Angeles</option>
</select>
```